# adjust table to fit text latex

Tags: tables, two-column, elsarticle

i'm trying to make a table in elsarticle two side but the table seems to overwrite the text.. can someone help me to fix the problem , here the code

```
 \\\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{l{2cm}l{2cm}l{2cm}l{2cm}l{2cm}l{2cm}l{2cm}l{2cm}l{2cm}l{2cm}}
 \hline
 & \textbf{MANF}&\textbf{CONSTR}&\textbf{ENERGY}& \textbf{TRSM}& \textbf{MMP}& \textbf{AGR}\\
  \hline
\textbf{MANF}&\0.2459 &1.0000 & & & & & \\
&0.03 & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & \\        
\textbf{CONSTR}&-0.1224 &0.2003 &1.0000 & & & & \\
&(0.18) &(0.05) & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & \\    
\textbf{ENRGY}&0.1304 &0.1030 &0.0969 &1.0000& & & \\
&(0.18)&(0.18) &(0.34) & & & & \\
& & & & & & & \\    
\textbf{TRSM}&0.1938 &0.1263 &0.0421 &0.2654&1.0000 & & \\
&(0.07) &(0.19) &(0.32)&(0.02) & & & \\
& & & & & & & \\    
\textbf{MMP}&-0.0259 &0.0725 &0.2624 &0.4186&0.1894 &1.0000 & \\
&(0.56) &(0.42) &(0.02) &(0.00) &(0.07) & & \\
& & & & & & & \\
\textbf{AGR}}&-0.1096 &0.1730 &0.3065 &-0.1168&0.0813 &0.0243 &1.0000 \\
&(0.17) &(0.11) &(0.01) &(0.16) &(0.33) &(0.53) & \\
& & & & & & & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
 \caption{Correlations of Residuals in SUR regression equation}
    \label{tab:Correlations of Residuals in SUR regression equation}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: `l{2cm}` is a syntax error you must have got multiple errors from that. After a TeX error you should not really look at the pdf at all, after an error tex tries to recover only to check more of the file, not to make sensible pdf output. perhaps you intended `p{2cm]` not `l{2cm}`. Please always post a complete document that shows the problem.

Comment: The table is probably too wide to fit reasonably. Use `\begin{table*}` instead of `\begin{table}[H]` then it will span across both columns